# What are good ways to randomize a million people into pairs?

Tags: contract-development

I came up with this, each person invokes the function that randomizes them into a pair, it generates a random pair, and if that pair is full, the function scans through pairs until it finds a vacant one. The contract memorizes regions that have been scanned through, and other people do not have to re-do the work that people before them have done, so that the last couple of people should be able to find a vacant pair.

```
contract randomizePairs {

    uint population_size;
    mapping(address => bool) inPopulation;
    mapping(uint => address[]) pair;
    mapping(address => uint) inPair;
    bytes32 entropy;
    mapping(uint => uint) iterationMemory;

    function commit() {
        require(inPopulation[msg.sender] == true);
        require(inPair[msg.sender] == 0);

        uint[] memorize;
        uint pairNumber = uint64(sha3(sha3(block.blockhash(block.number), entropy), now)) % (population_size / 2);

        if(pair[pairNumber].length < 2) {
            pair[pairNumber].push(msg.sender);
            inPair[msg.sender] = pairNumber;
        }
        else {
            memorize.push(pairNumber); // memorize from this point
            for(uint i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                pairNumber = (pairNumber + i) % (population_size / 2); // continues from 0 when it reaches population_size
                if(pair[pairNumber].length == 2) {
                    if(iterationMemory[pairNumber] != 0) {
                        memorize.push(iterationMemory[pairNumber]); // memorize from that point
                        pairNumber = iterationMemory[pairNumber] - i; // skip the pairs that have been scanned by other people
                    }
                }
                else {
                    pair[pairNumber].push(msg.sender);
                    inPair[msg.sender] = pairNumber;
                    break; 
                }
            }
            // record the regions with full pairs up to the current pair
            for(uint m = 0; m < memorize.length; m++) {
                iterationMemory[mem[m]] = pairNumber;
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: whatever is a good way to randomize a million people into pairs, on-state, is of my interest. it's not an infinite loop, should be within gas-boundaries of course, 100 iterations seemed quite low I've run much more than that on the test net some year ago, and the loop only runs when a pair isn't found, or, one isn't close to the random pair that was generated, will not run at all for majority of all people.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation - deleted my previous comment :-)

Comment: what do you think of the solution I came up with? see the answer I wrote

Comment: it has no for loops, minimal computation per pair

Comment: This is a very good example of operation to avoid on a blockchain based system. There are other paradigm but sorting to efficiently move in a set. Sorting derives from a world built on sequential machinery. The blockchain itself is a good example of non-sorting. You must avoid “to scan” trough a dataset (I.e. to use a “for”) every time your dataset is very big or undefined. Bubble sort is not for blockchain based systems. By the way, neither it is “randomizing”. This system is not a good idea on Ethereum. You are managing a database here. Move it to standard computation or math forum.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this, all people are in an ordered list from 0 to population_size, and each person commits, generating a random number between 0 and `list.length`, and that is a pair. At the same time, they replace the people at the position they and their random partner were at in the list, adding from the beginning and end of the list, shrinking `list.length`, so that at the last pair there are only a few people left in the list. Throughout, never the possibility to select a person already in a pair, as the list updates itself.

The list is stored in a mapping, so that it is trivial to re-arrange people,

```
mapping(address => uint) ID;
```

and the boundaries could be uints,

```
uint beginning;
uint end;
```

Here's an implementation I wrote now, some of it is biased to the dApp I work on,

```
mapping(address => uint) pseudonymID; // an ordered list of all pseudonyms, used for generating pseudonym pairs, and more
mapping(uint => address) pseudonymIndex; // an ordered list of all pseudonyms, used for generating pseudonym pairs, and more

uint beginning; // used for pruning the list from the beginning
uint end; // used for pruning the list from the end
uint pairCount; // used for generating pairs
bytes32 entropy; // used for generating random numbers

mapping(uint => address[]) pair;

function sortingHat() {
  uint ID = pseudonymID[msg.sender];
  require(ID != 0);
  uint randomNumber = uint64(sha3(sha3(block.blockhash(block.number), entropy), now)) % listLength();
  address randomPeer = pseudonymIndex[randomNumber];
  pair[pairCount][0] = msg.sender;
  pair[pairCount][1] = randomPeer;
  pairCount++;
  address fromBeginning = pseudonymIndex[beginning];
  address fromEnd = pseudonymIndex[end];
  pseudonymIndex[ID] = fromBeginning;
  pseudonymIndex[randomPeer] = fromEnd;
  pseudonymID[fromBeginning] = ID;
  pseudonymID[fromEnd] = randomPeer;
  delete pseudonymIndex[beginning];
  delete pseudonymIndex[end];
  delete pseudonymID[msg.sender];
  delete pseudonymID[randomPeer];
  beginning++;
  end--;
  entropy = sha3(randomNumber, msg.sender, randomPeer);
}

function listLength() returns (uint) {
return end - beginning;
}
```